# How to activate the user search

Tags: users, search, wp-user-query

I'm trying to activate the user search in my wordpress site. Which means that I want also the users on the search result. I have tried some plugins, but none of these gives the solution I want. Is there some code snippet that I can put on `functions.php` that helps to solve my problem? Do I have to use `WP_User_Query`? Thanks!

So far I have used these plugins:

- Relevanssi
- Search everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a great tutorial [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/05/front-end-author-listing-user-search-wordpress/) that have helped me to developing a custom user search. This is my solution:

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Simple User Listing
Description: Create a simple shortcode to list our WordPress users.
Author: Damiano Fossa
Version: 1.6.3
*/

function sul_user_listing($atts, $content = null) {
    global $post;
    global $wpdb;

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "role" => 'tecnico',
        "number" => '10'
    ), $atts));

    $role = sanitize_text_field($role);
    $number = sanitize_text_field($number);

    // We're outputting a lot of HTML, and the easiest way 
    // to do it is with output buffering from PHP.
    ob_start();

    // Get the Search Term
    $search = ( isset($_GET["as"]) ) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET["as"]) : false ;

    // Get Query Var for pagination. This already exists in WordPress
    $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    // Calculate the offset (i.e. how many users we should skip)
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $number;

    if ($search) {

        $my_users = new WP_User_Query(
            array( 
                'role' => 'tecnico',
                'search' => '*' . $search . '*',
                'search_columns' => array(
                    'user_login',
                    'user_nicename',
                    'user_email',
                    'user_url',
                    'display_name'
                )
            )
        );
    } else {
        // Generate the query 
        $my_users = new WP_User_Query(
            array( 
                'role' => 'asdlol'
            )
        );
    }

    // Get the total number of authors. Based on this, offset and number 
    // per page, we'll generate our pagination. 
    $total_authors = $my_users->total_users;

    // Calculate the total number of pages for the pagination
    $total_pages = intval($total_authors / $number) + 1;

    // The authors object. 
    $authors = $my_users->get_results();
?>

<style>

.advance-search .real-btn {
    margin: 0;
}

</style>

<section class="advance-search ">
    <form method="get" id="sul-searchform" class="advance-search-form clearfix" action="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <div class="option-bar small">
            <input type="text" class="field" name="as" id="sul-s" placeholder="Cerca tecnico" />
        </div>
        <div class="option-bar">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class=" real-btn btn"  id="sul-searchsubmit" value="Cerca" />
        </div>
    </form>
  <?php 
  if($search) { ?>
    <h2>Ricerca: <em><?php echo $search; ?></em></h2>
    <!--<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Back To Author Listing</a>-->
  <?php } ?>

</section><!-- .author-search -->

<?php if (!empty($authors)) { ?>
    <ul class="author-list">
        <?php
            // loop through each author
            foreach($authors as $author) {
                $author_info = get_userdata($author->ID);
            ?>
            <li>
                <?php if(!empty($author->pie_profile_pic_5)): ?>
                <img width="130" height="130" src="<?php echo $author->pie_profile_pic_5; ?>" 
                                                     class="attachment-agent-image wp-post-image" alt="<?php echo $author->first_name; ?> <?php echo $author->last_name; ?>">
                <h2 style="display: inline; margin-left: 20px;">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($author->ID); ?>"><?php echo $author->first_name; ?> <?php echo $author->last_name; ?></a>
                    - <?php echo count_user_posts( $author->ID ); ?> immobili
                </h2>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <h2 style="display: inline;">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($author->ID); ?>"><?php echo $author->first_name; ?> <?php echo $author->last_name; ?></a>
                        - <?php echo count_user_posts($author->ID, "property"); ?> immobili
                    </h2>
                <?php endif; ?>

              <p><?php //echo $author_info->description; ?></p>
              <?php $latest_post = new WP_Query( "author=$author->ID&post_count=1" ); 
              if (!empty($latest_post->post)){ ?>
              <p><strong>Latest Article:</strong>
              <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($latest_post->post->ID) ?>">
                <?php echo get_the_title($latest_post->post->ID) ;?>
              </a></p>
              <?php } //endif ?>
              <!--<p><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($author->ID); ?> ">Maggiori informazioni.. <?php //echo $author_info->display_name; ?></a></p>-->
            </li>
        <?php  } ?>
    </ul> <!-- .author-list -->
<?php } else {

            if(!empty($search)){
                $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT user_id
                        FROM wp_usermeta
                        WHERE meta_key = 'pie_address_3' AND meta_value LIKE '%s'", "%" . $search . "%");

            $ids = $wpdb->get_results($query); ?> 
            <ul class="author-list"> 
                <?php
                foreach ($ids as $id) { ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php if(!empty(get_user_meta($id->user_id, "pie_profile_pic_5", true))): ?>
                            <img width="90" height="90" src="<?php echo get_user_meta($id->user_id, "pie_profile_pic_5", true); ?>" 
                                                             class="attachment-agent-image wp-post-image">
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <h2 style="display: inline; margin-left: 20px;">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($id->user_id); ?>">
                                <?php if(!empty(get_the_author_meta("first_name", $id->user_id))): ?>
                                    <?php echo get_the_author_meta('first_name', $id->user_id); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if(!empty(get_the_author_meta("last_name", $id->user_id))): ?>
                                    <?php echo get_the_author_meta('last_name', $id->user_id); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </a>
                            - <?php echo count_user_posts($id->user_id); ?> immobili
                        </h2>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
    <?php } ?>

  <!--<h2>Nessun tecnico trovato</h2>-->
<? } //endif ?>

  <nav id="nav-single" style="clear:both; float:none; margin-top:20px;">
    <!--<h3 class="assistive-text">Post navigation</h3>-->
    <?php if ($page != 1) { ?>
      <span class="nav-previous"><a rel="prev" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>page/<?php echo $page - 1; ?>/"><span class="meta-nav">←</span> Previous</a></span>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ($page < $total_pages ) { ?>
      <span class="nav-next"><a rel="next" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>page/<?php echo $page + 1; ?>/">Next <span class="meta-nav">→</span></a></span>
    <?php } ?>
  </nav>


  <?php 
  // Output the content.
  $output = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();


  // Return only if we're inside a page. This won't list anything on a post or archive page. 
  if (is_page()) return  $output;

}

// Add the shortcode to WordPress. 
add_shortcode('userlisting', 'sul_user_listing');
?>
```